# SQL select other column with count

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions, outer-join

We need a SQL query to get the following output.

Note: Table contains millions of records. Need an optimized query

```
Select 
       E.EmpId, E.EmpName, E.Salary,
       (select count(*) from Dept where EmpId=E.EmpId) as DeptCount
from Employee E
```

[image]

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Please in code questions give a [mre]. [ask] [Help] PS  [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/3404097)

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `OUTER JOIN` with `COUNT` aggregate.

`Count` aggregate function would not be counted when the value is `NULL`

```
 SELECT e.EmpId, e.EmpName, e.Salary,COUNT(d.EmpId) DeptCount
 FROM Employee e
 LEFT JOIN Dept d
 ON  d.EmpId = e.EmpId
 GROUP BY e.EmpId, e.EmpName, e.Salary
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=17ec3edd52da066e2097cccfbaf9ff05)